# elseif not working

Tags: php, if-statement

This doesn't make sense.. I'm trying to sort posts according to the value of a URL parameter but my elseif statement isn't working.

This is a function that adds another WHERE clause to the query. There are no MYSQL errors I'm just having statement trouble.

```
function sort_where($where)
{
  if (isset($_GET['sort'])) { 
      $sort = $_GET['sort'];

      if ($sort = "up") {
         $where .= " AND $sort > 1";
      } 
      elseif ($sort = "down") {
         $where .= " AND $sort > 1";
      }

   }

  return $where;
}
```

The query eventually looks like this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE something = $something AND $sort > 1";
```

The if statement works, the elseif is ignored. I get posts with `up > 1` regardless or vice-versa if `$sort = down` in the if statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, neither of the two inner ifs are working correctly.

You need to use `==` not `=`. One equals sign means assignment, and if you assign to a truthy value it always evaluates to true in an if condition. That's why your elseif appears to never happen.

You may also need to fix your `WHERE` clauses, they don't make sense to me (you're sorting but comparing to an `up` column and a `down` column?). Or maybe that's how you designed your table...

---

Based on your comments, try the following SQL `WHERE` clauses and see if you get the correct posts:

```
if ($sort == "up") {
   $where .= " AND up > down";
} 
elseif ($sort == "down") {
   $where .= " AND down > up";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's always the most basic things that trouble me lol. Yes up and down are columns in my table. Im sorting posts with UP and DOWN votes

Comment: Ah I see. Are you trying to filter only upvoted posts or downvoted posts, or sorting by their scores?

Comment: by their scores. I'm actually trying to do `up > down` and vise-versa (not sure if possible). I just used "1" in the example.

Comment: @Noob: Are your scores calculated as `up - down`? That's how SO's system works.

Comment: @BoltClock hmm `-` ? For example I have post 18 with `up = 8` and `down = 5`. If `sort = up` I query posts `WHERE up > down` thus post 18 will display and others with UP votes greater than DOWN votes. This if I can compare UP and DOWN rather than UP with some value

Comment: @Noob: I added the amended SQL to my answer. See if it works for you.

Comment: @BoltClock thanks! It works :) I haven't tried comparing two columns before but it's much more effective than using a number value.

Answer (score 1):

Single = means variable 1 = variable 2

Double == means compare

Also if you are going to use this code make sure you put mysql_real_escape_string() around your $_GET statements or anything that has user inputs or people will be able to use sql injection.

E.g. mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sort']) and if you are using it multiple times makes sure you use a variable

Here is the corrected code ;)

```
function sort_where($where)
{
  if (isset($_GET['sort'])) { 
      $sort = $_GET['sort'];

      if ($sort == "up") {
         $where .= " AND $sort > 1";
      } 
      elseif ($sort == "down") {
         $where .= " AND $sort > 1";
      }

   }

  return $where;
}
```

Comment: I mean, do an `if (isset($_GET['sort']))`, then if it's set, `mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sort'])`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($sort = "up")
elseif ($sort = "down")
```

should be

```
if ($sort == "up")
elseif ($sort == "down")
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

```
  if ($sort = "up") {
```

`=` is the assignment operator.  You need to use `==` here if you want to test for equality.

Also, the body of both conditionals:

```
  if ($sort = "up") {
     $where .= " AND $sort > 1";
  } 
  elseif ($sort = "down") {
     $where .= " AND $sort > 1";
  }
```

Are identical.  I don't think you mean to append the same basic string to the query, do you?  (Granted `$sort` will be different in either case, but why not just hardcode the strings in if that's what you mean anyway.  This just reads really confusing, and it's hard to tell exactly what your intent is.)

Comment: Thx for the answer! :) In actuality I'm not comparing the $sort to teh same value.